# Triage Reviewing: Question Display Is Incorrect?

Tags: bug, review-queues

I was reviewing some questions and I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18860658):
[image]

It says that the question was asked today and there were zero votes. But when I clicked on the acutal [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501122/create-non-capturing-method-reference-which-will-call-superclass-method), this is what I get:
[image]

There were seven votes, the question was asked 20 days ago, and there were more than 100 views.

My question is, is this a bug? If not, then what is the point of keeping this question in the review query if it has been well-received?

Note: I have passed the review audits...

Comment: That's the same image...

Comment: Are we playing "spot the difference" or what?

Comment: This is where Free Hand Circles really shine

Comment: Oops, my bad. I had a different image.

Comment: @Laurel See my edited post.

Comment: @DavyM ????????